# Stored Procedure exceptions not being detected by JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am running a stored procedure using a prepared statement jdbc template:

```
conn = dbrm.getConnection(this.dataSources.get(aas.getArgumentValue("dataSource")));
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
try{
    boolean hasResultSet = stmt.execute(query);
catch(Exception e){
    // log and handle appropriately
}
```

My stored procedure is basically one stored procedure calling two other stored procedures.

The problem that I am having is that if there is an exception after the first statement of the stored procedure then the exception does not come back to the jdbc template so it appears that my stored procedure worked to my java code even if it didn't which is obviously problematic.

Is there a way to manually check the output of a stored procedure or make all possible exceptions bubble up to the java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that when a stored procedure is executed, exceptions that are raised may get "queued" behind a successful result. In order to "retrieve" the exception we may have to use the `getMoreResults` method of the `CallableStatement` object.

For example, given the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table1sp] AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 123;
    CREATE TABLE #Table1 (textcol VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY);
    INSERT INTO #Table1 (textcol) VALUES (NULL);  -- error here
END
```

If we run the Java code

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;"
        + "databaseName=myDb;" + "integratedSecurity=true";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call Table1sp}")) {
        cs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        rs.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

then we just print the value `123` and our code carries on as if nothing was wrong.

However, if we follow-up with a `getMoreResults()` call ...

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;"
        + "databaseName=myDb;" + "integratedSecurity=true";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call Table1sp}")) {
        cs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        rs.close();

        try {
            cs.getMoreResults();
        } catch (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLServerException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

... then the exception gets caught:

```
123
SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'textcol', table 'tempdb.dbo.#Table1 ...
```

Comment: Excellent answer, in getMoreResults will the exception be as text or a throwable?

Comment: It is a real live`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException`, thrown by the `getMoreResults` call itself.

Comment: Getting the resultset solves it -- I had SET NOCOUNT ON, and have no results in the stored procedure,  it wouldn't catch raiserror until getting result set after execute.  Thanks.