# JDBC SQLException Catching Throw exception from stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have following code:

```
public Boolean insertCollectible(Collectible c) {
        checkConnection();
        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("{call spNewCollectible(?,?)}");){
            ps.setInt(1, c.getGame_id());
            ps.setString(2, c.getCollectible_name());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
```

For calling stored procedure which looks like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spNewCollectible(@game_id INT, @name VARCHAR(50)) AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT * FROM Collectible JOIN Collectible_instance ON Collectible_instance.collectible_id = Collectible.collectible_id WHERE Collectible.game_id = @game_id
            IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
                THROW 51010, 'Nelze přidat předměty po zahájení distribuce předmětů', 1; 
            ELSE BEGIN
                IF(SELECT COUNT(collectible_id)FROM Game JOIN Collectible ON Collectible.game_id = Game.game_id WHERE Game.game_id = @game_id GROUP BY Game.game_id)>=10
                    THROW 51011, 'Byl dosažen maximální počet předmětů', 1; 
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO Collectible (game_id, collectible_name)VALUES (@game_id, @name)
            END
            COMMIT;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK;
            THROW;
        END CATCH   
END
```

My problem is, that THROW exceptions do not get caught by SQLException and insertCollectible returns True value even though procedure ended at an THROW Exception. Procedure itself works fine after testing in sql server.

Comment: The exception won't be raised in the app code until you consume the results and invoke `rs.next()`. See [The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).

Comment: See [java - Stored Procedure exceptions not being detected by JDBC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711306/stored-procedure-exceptions-not-being-detected-by-jdbc)